# How do add new index to array in foreach loop?

Tags: php

I have a array which structure is

```
<?php
$a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
$b = [];
?>
```

I want to add indexes of variable `$a` one by one to variable `$b`.

Comment: Don't understand. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: what you get exactly in response of this array ?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I want to achieve that when foreach loops starts , I want to add tha content `$a` into `$b` one by one.

Comment: @jilesh i want to get the result
`$b = [1,2,3,4,5,6];`

Comment: if you want same result than declare $b = $a but not need to do this

Comment: Can you put your issue in a context? It's hard to understand why you want this.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld  In view page the users are being listed and i have check the wether the user is listed above or not.

Comment: Yeah ok, but why would you need to copy the keys? It seems you're looking for a comparision function rather than a "copying" function ?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I have used the code from the answers and it worked!

Comment: @IlyasDattoo - great! :-)

Comment: Please delete this question. This is not a usefull question.

Answer (score 3):

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
$b = array_keys($a);
```

Comment: This would not actually be the same result because first key is 0 and first value of $a is 1.

Answer (score 2):

```
$b = array_values($a); 
or you can do as follows :
foreach ($a as $v){ 
  array_push($b, $v); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like this,

```
$a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

foreach ($a as $key => $value){
    $b[] = $key;
}
```

Comment: This would not actually be the same result because first key is 0 and first value of $a is 1.

Comment: I think he wants to add the array keys in array b and that's what the solution is for.

Comment: Aha.. He said in comment he wanted to add content from $a. Therefore the missunderstanding...! (content and key is not same for me)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
foreach (array(1, 2, 3, 4) as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand from your question

```
<?php
$a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
$b = array();

for ($i=0; $i < count($a) ; $i++) { 
    array_push($b, $i);

}
print_r($b);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($a as $v){
    $b[] = $v;
}
```

Or if you just want to copy the array, you can use array_merge instead:

```
$b = array_merge(array(), $a);
```

I misunderstood the question a bit. If you want to copy the keys and not the value you could do like this with foreach-loop:

```
foreach ($a as $k=>$v){
    $b[] = $k;
}
```

Other suggestion like array_keys would work as well.